# Does a member variable need to be volatile if no concurrent writes occur?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, java-memory-model

If a member variable is updated by one thread and later read (not updated) by other treads from a thread pool, does that member variable needs to be declared as volatile?

Made-up code to illustrate the question: A filter that uses a positive-list reference that is updated before used (read) in parallel:

```
public class PetFilter {
    private final PositiveListProvider positiveNameListProvider;

    private Set<String> positiveNameList;   // Should be volatile?

    public PetFilter(PositiveListProvider positiveNameListProvider) {
        this.positiveNameListProvider = positiveNameListProvider;
    }

    public List<Pet> getFiltered(List<Pet> unfiltered) {
        // assume that getPositiveList returns a new reference
        this.positiveNameList = positiveNameListProvider.getPositiveList();  // written by caller thread
        return unfiltered.stream().parallel().filter(this::accept).toList();
    }

    private boolean accept(Pet candidate) {
        return positiveNameList.contains(candidate.getName());  // read by threads form ForkJoinPool.commonPool
    }
}
```

I'm aware that volatile guarantees that all threads "see" the current value, but is it **required** for positiveNameList in this example?

My gut tells me that positiveNameList does not need to be volatile.

But viewed from the threading perspective, positiveNameList is updated by the caller thread and then read by threads from the ForkJoinPool.commonPool which might have "seen" an older reference of PositiveListProvider in earlier executions of the getFiltered() method.

Either way, I'd also be interested in where in the [JLS spec for the memory model the](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) the behavior is described.

Comment: If there some kind of synchronization mechanism is sitting between writing and reading that variable, then that synchronization mechanism creates a happens before edge between the 2 actions. E.g. if you would have a plain employee Pojo created on thread 1 and put on some thread-safe queue and read by thread 2 from that queue, then the queue will introduce the happens-before edge needed to prevent running into a data race. If no such a synchronization mechanism exists, then you have probably a data race on your hands.

Comment: Executors guarantee that such a synchronization mechanism exists:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html and look for memory consistency effects.

Comment: @pveentjer Thank you, I think this is correct. Runnables see what "happend before" they were submitted to an Executor, no volatile necessary in the case I described. If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You are storing the reference to a set (inconsistently called “list”) provided by some external code (`positiveNameListProvider.getPositiveList()`) in the field `positiveNameList`. So this code entirely relies on the provider being well-behaving, i.e. not modifying the list in another thread. If the provider is not well-behaving, declaring the variable as `volatile` wouldn’t help anyway.

Comment: Further note that if `getFiltered` is invoked by multiple threads concurrently, it will also break, regardless of the field being `volatile` or not. But it would be easy to make this class immune to such problems, as there is no reason to store the reference into a field at all. It’s only used within a single `getFiltered` operation. So, don’t store the list in a field  but a local variable and replace `this::accept` with a lambda expression `candidate -> positiveNameList.contains( candidate.getName())`, then, `getFiltered` is safe for invocation by multiple threads.

Comment: @Holger Could you explain what would break if getFiltered is invoked concurrently? Worst case I'd see is that an ongoing concurrent filtering could see a newer positiveNameList for some of its processing.

Comment: It could see *any* list, newer or older. And if it does see a list created by a different thread, it either needs `volatile` or a thread safe list implementation, otherwise, it can break in various ways. But even if you use `volatile`, a parallel stream does not specify in which order elements are processed (that would contradict parallel processing), so the result is still based on the use of old and new lists in an arbitrary mixture.